# Hide / Unhide entire rows based on check box selection

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I would like to hide specific rows based on whether a check box is ticked.

I have this code but it does not seem to work.

I right clicked on the check box, and assigned this macro:

```
Private Sub CheckBox68_Click()
    If CheckBox68 = True Then
        [24:26].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure why it does not work. Can anyone see something wrong with it?

Many thanks in advance
Ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in your code where you hide the rows.
You need to to modify it as below:

```
Private Sub CheckBox68_Click()
    [24:26].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox68.value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mielk, It still does not seem to work. I get an error message saying "Compile error: Ambiguous name detected: CheckBox68_click()"

Comment: It seems that you have two methods with the same name now. You need to delete the previous version of `Private Sub CheckBox68_Click()` before pasting this one proposed by me.

Comment: It still does not work I am afraid. :(. I right clicked on the check box, assigned a macro, did a copy and paste of your code. I made sure the name of the check box matches with your code name reference.

Comment: Got it! I was using the standard "check box (form control) rather than the "check box (activex control)". Many thanks for your help Mielk